# Excel VBA code is not showing and it and the file is not saving - Sharepoint file

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

so this morning I turned on my computer to find that when I opened my Excel macro-enabled file, I found that I was unable to access or view any of my workbook-specific modules at all, and even saving the workbook throws errors.

A list of the problems I am experiencing (in no particular order):

- Putting "stop" into the immediate window and running it throws error number 32809.
- All .xlsm files also show this error message when trying to save to Sharepoint (or locally!): *"Errors were detected while saving (filename). Microsoft excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features. To make the repairs in a new file click Continue. To cancel saving the file click Cancel*.
- I have tried saving the workbook-specific modules to little success (Excel becomes unresponsive when I try)
- I have tried restarting my computer and these same problems persist.
- Attempting to copy sheets into a new file gives the error: *"Module not found"*

Is the only way to solve this to copy everything into a new file? Is there any way to salvage my VBA code? Many thanks for you help.

Comment: Hard to say what the problem is, but the file may be corrupted. Do you have a backup somewhere?

Comment: I have - they are mostly like this. I'm wondering whether it is due to some of the formatting I've used - when I try and download and save versions of the file I get a message "Damage to the file was so extensive that repairs were not possible. Excel attempted to save your formulas and values, but some data may have been lost or corrupted", so I guess you're probably right. But because it is 5+ files that are all backups, it suggests it might be a common issue due to the formatting. I'm in contact with an IT specialist at the moment, if they come up with an answer I'll post it here

Comment: Aha! It seems that the files had the same name as other files - and on Sharepoint this is a big mistake, even if in a different folder! I have deleted duplicate name files and renamed my copies when creating them, and hopefully this will solve the issue. I don't have time to do this will all of my files right now, but will update if it fixes everything.

Comment: If that is indeed the solution to the problem, answer your own question and mark it as answered. This will help others with the same problem find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with Sharepoint itself. Sharepoint is weird in the way that it handles file names, so having one file with the same name as another, even if it is in a different folder (or has a different extension it seems), doesn't throw a file naming error but will seriously mess up your file system with the errors listed in the question.

Luckily, upon naming the file a different name, the issues seem (!) to be resolved.

(Answering my own Q here so that others can find an answer if they have similar problems).